# PHP syntax question

Tags: php, comparison, ternary-operator

I found this line of code and I'm trying to comprehend what it's doing. The part I'm not familiar with is the question mark and the colon. What are these characters used for?

```
$string = $array[1] . ($array[0] === 47 ? '' : ' word');
```

Comment: This is the conditional operator.  It is also a type of ternary operator (simply because it has 3 operands) and often folks make the mistake of calling it _the_ ternary operator which doesn't really make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Also this is a duplicate, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889373/quick-php-syntax-question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276909/php-syntax-question-what-does-the-question-mark-and-colon-mean.

Comment: @Andrew -- silly or not, the PHP manual has named this construct The Ternary Operator, so it's not a mistake to refer to it as such http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-and-identity-comparison-operators-differ for your next question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a ternary operator; basically a short-hand conditional.

It's the same as:

```
$string = $array[1];

if ($array[0] !== 47)
    $string .= ' word';
```

See [this section in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (the "Ternary Operator" section).

Answer (score 0):

That's the ternary operator.

Here's a reference to a [tutorial](http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/tutorials/using_if_else_ternary_operators.htm)

It works somehow like this:

```
function tern()

    if ($array[0] === 47)
    {
        return '';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'word';
    }
}
```