# a simple php syntax question

Tags: php

i just want to know from below code what does `?` and `:` specify, i would appreciate if someone explain me the below code. thank you

```
$country = empty($_POST['country']) ? die ("ERROR: Enter a country") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['country']);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [quick php syntax question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889373/quick-php-syntax-question) Come on, it is nearly the same title ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called **ternary** operator and is simply **shorthand** of this code:

```
if (empty($_POST['country']))
{
  die ("ERROR: Enter a country");
}
else
{
  $country = mysql_escape_string($_POST['country']);
}
```

**Syntax:**

```
condition ? used if true : used if false;
```

Or you can do assignments:

```
variable = condition ? used if true : used if false;
```

**More Info:**

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4

Comment: thank you i was expecting an answer like this, i am not used to shorthand.. thank you for this reply.. :)

Comment: Good answer, +1, but you forgot to add `$country = ` to the `else` block

Comment: @Igor Zinov'yevL Yes forgot to add that, thanks :)

Comment: For more information, here's the syntax of the ternary operator : condition ? value if true : value if false

Comment: Hi there,

in the else condidtion i want to echo something like a link to go back to index page, i tried using concatenation and it is not happening.. check the last string

$user = empty($_POST['user']) ? die("Error : Please enter username") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['user']) . echo "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']";

how do i achieve this??

Comment: First off, in this case you would be better off with a full if/else statement, this whole thing is totally unreadable. And the problem here, I think, is that concatenation operator has a higher precedence. So you need to do it this way: `$condition ? ($if_true) : ($if_false . $concatenated_string);`

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: To redirect to index page use `header("location: index.php");`

Answer (score 1):

See this:

[PHP syntax question: What does the question mark and colon mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276909/php-syntax-question-what-does-the-question-mark-and-colon-mean-closed)

It is the ternary operator in PHP as well as other languages.

Answer (score 1):

`$country = empty($_POST['country']) ? die ("ERROR: Enter a country") :`

I suppose this script accepts data from a form sent by POST method. If country variable is empty, exit the script with error message.

`mysql_escape_string($_POST['country']);`

This function should return escaped value from given variable. Therefore it should be written like this

`$country = mysql_escape_string($_POST['country']);`

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$country = empty($_POST['country']) ?
           die ("ERROR: Enter a country") :
           mysql_escape_string($_POST['country']);
```

If the expression `empty($_POST['country'])` evaluates to `true`, then `die ("ERROR: Enter a country")` will be evaluated (and the result would be assigned to `$country`, but for the fact that `die()` halts script execution).

On the other hand, if `empty($_POST['country'])` evaluates to `false`, then `mysql_escape_string($_POST['country'])` will be evaluated, and the result will be assigned to `$country`.

Comment: Hi there,

in the else condidtion i want to echo something like a link to go back to index page, i tried using concatenation and it is not happening.. check the last string

$user = empty($_POST['user']) ? die("Error : Please enter username") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['user']) . echo "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']";     

how do i achieve this??

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. If you use `$user = empty($_POST['user']) ? die("Error : Please enter username") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['user']).$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` then assuming the call to `empty()` returns false, `$User` will be `mysql_escape_string($_POST['user'])` concatenated with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. If you actually want to `echo` something conditionally, perhaps it would be best for you to go with an `if ... else` approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's test condition: if variable from HTML FORM is empty then print out "ERROR: Enter a country", else set variable **country** safe characters..