# What does this PHP line mean?

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me what this PHP line is doing?

```
$fileName = (isset($_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME])) ? $_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME] : null;
```

Comment: if the $PARAM_FILE_NAME parameter has been set by POST request, assign its value to $fileName else assign null to $fileName

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary <-- the ternary operator. Example in the docs is equivalent to yours.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889373/quick-php-syntax-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is simply a shorthand php `if|else` statement.

Expanded, it would look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME])) {
    $fileName = $_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME];
} else {
    $fileName = null;
}
```

You can read more about it [**`here`**](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples).

It is basically a shorter assigning of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileName = (isset($_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME])) ? $_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME] : null;
```

It sets the variable named $fileName to either the value of $_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME] or to null. Another way to write it is:

```
if (isset($_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME]))
    $fileName = $_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME];
else
    $fileName = null;
```

This avoids a warning if the key in $_POST isn't set, which would you get with the more straightforward version:

```
$fileName = $_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME];
```